# Website css loads fast except for for the source tabs

Tags: css

I have a website richanime.com and it's a anime based website. The problem is when i load any of my posts the tabs don't load immediately. I've tried to load the jquery and jquery-ui.css internally and still no luck.

It loads a little bit faster on opera and chrome, but on firefox the page loads without and then with the css for the tabs. Can anyone please check it out, here's an example post: http://richanime.net/anime/fairy-tail-2014-episode-46/ (It's the tabs that say "Mp4Upload", "VideoNest" and such.

I use jquery-1.9.1.js and jquery-ui.js while jquery-ui.css loads in my style.css

I use wordpress. The problem lies on opera and and chrome too but firefox the most. Does anyone have any idea how to make it load immediately?

Here's some code: [Style.css](http://richanime.net/tabsstyle.css) for tabs only

I've added some the css code that i use for the tabs. Hope it's enough.

Comment: fairy tail, nice anime;
maybe you give us more code and a unabridged version of your css

Comment: Here's my whole css link
http://richanime.net/wp-content/themes/AnimeSlider/style.css
Any help please? :P

Comment: unreadable, please short your css and give some html code

Comment: http://richanime.net/stylesimple.css
||
http://richanime.net/phpcode.txt
I've narrowed it really down. The other link is the php code that i use with the css.